# Configuração de CSS para impressora matricial

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, impressão

Bom, meu problema é o seguinte. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web e utilizo ASP.NET MVC, consegui gerar uma guia aonde o *layout* que apresento é *null*. Porém não consegui configurar a impressão corretamente para uma impressora matricial.

O tamanho da folha matricial é meia página (*Width*: 21,4 / *Height*: 13,7).
Qual seria o melhor tamanho da página, fonte e tamanho de fonte para tal impressão? Ou tais configurações são realizadas direto na impressora?

> PS: Tentei o código abaixo e não surtiu o efeito esperado.
>
> PS²: Estou utilizando o `window.print();` para chamar o modal de impressão no chrome.

```
@media print {
    html, body {
        width: 5.5in; /* was 8.5in */
        height: 8.5in; /* was 5.5in */
        display: block;
        font-family: "Calibri";
        /*font-size: auto; NOT A VALID PROPERTY */
    }

    @page {
        size: 5.5in 8.5in /* . Random dot? */;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu tive um problema parecido com impressão em impressoras térmicas no Firefox. Pra resolver o problema do layout da página tive que usar o menu "Configurar página" no Firefox e deixar personalizado para aquele tipo de papel (margens, orientação e tamanho).

O problema é que ele fica configurado sempre com aquele tipo de impressão.

Comment: E também teria que configurar em cada impressora isso também.

Comment: Talvez este post possa lhe ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13797130/2238515

Comment: @CleverAlmeida obrigado pela resposta, a intenção é realmente essa. O problema é que não sei o estilo certo (fonte, tamanho, margin, padding) para a impressão matricial. E é exatamente o que eu preciso.